# How to bind base64 data in a django form ImageField

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, forms

I'm implementing an ajax form submission that resizes images before submitting them. The javascript basically reads the file as an `Image`, resizes and draws to `canvas`, and then appends the data to a `FormData` object:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image0", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

I then do an ajax submission to my django view, verifying with a `ModelForm`:

#### forms.py

```
class InsertProduct(forms.ModelForm):
    image0 = forms.ImageField(
        required=True, 
        max_length=64, 
        widget=forms.FileInput( attrs={"id": "image0",} )
    )
```

#### views.py

```
def ajax_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InsertProduct(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.POST.urlencode())
        print(form.errors)
```

The `urlencode()` tells me that I'm receiving the data:

```
image0=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABE...
```

But the form errors tells me that I'm not binding it properly:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>image0<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

Maybe the ImageField is looking for the data in request.FILES instead of request.POST? How do I get this working?

Comment: Yes, it looks for it in request.FILES why are you not sending it that way? Base64 encoding and uploading is a waste. Ads roughly 30% to the size of the packet.

Comment: This is a simplified example - the real application has multiple images. The risk that I'm trying to mitigate is that someone uploads 10-20Mb of images that need to be resized down to 400-500kb server side. It will be much faster to resize in the browser (in parallel while the user completes the form) than on the server. (I'm also not paying for server bandwidth, but I am paying for CPU cores). Is it possible to either bind the data to `request.FILES` in javascript, or alternatively get the `ImageField` from `request.POST`?

Comment: Have you looked at blueimp jquery upload. Seems to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a short answer is to use an image library such as pillow to convert base64 back to an `Image` file, and manually save.

However, if you can rely on the browser's `FormData` API, you can do:

```
var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
var quality = 0.95;
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    fd.set("image0", blob, "myimage.jpg");
}, "image/jpeg", quality);
```

Note that Chrome only supports FormData `set` and `append` from the latest stable release 50, and my build throws an exception when I try to `set` a blob. It seems Firefox 46 will do it (`set` and `append` are suppored since 44 I think), but only if FormData() is initialised from a DOM `<form>` element. If you inspect POST you'll find that a file input field (that was not present in the DOM and is appended after) is missing otherwise.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, it's possible to send the image as a file wtihout base64 with certain libraries such as https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload (I am not associated wtih it)